# How can I modify this Select2 javascript to enable paging?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, linq-to-entities, jquery-select2

I am not too familiar with javascript, so I need help here. I have this method which returns a list of Customers (2000+), so the Select2 dropdown hangs.  I want to enable paging, but I am not sure what I need to change.  Here is my javascript code:

```
var GetCutomerDDL = function(cient) {

    var Json = {},
        customers = [];

    $ddlCustomers.select2('val', '');
    Json.client = cient;

    $.post(urlContent + 'Cutomer/GetCustomerDDL', Json, function(data) {
    }, 'json').done(function(data) {
        customers = data;
        $ddlCustomers.select2({
            placeholder: "Select Customer(s)",
            allowClear: true,
            multiple: true,
            data: customers
        });
    });

};
```

`GetCustomerDDL` uses LINQ to just return all the customers, but I want to enable paging so don't load over 2000 records in a dropdown at once.  What do I need to change in the javascript and the server side?

Answer (score 9):

The Select2 control includes ["infinite scrolling"](http://select2.github.io/select2/#infinite).  That may be what you're looking for.

Scroll2's main page is found here: http://select2.github.io/

On the server-side, you'll want to use `Skip()` and `Take()` LINQ operators to skip forward in the data and to take only a certain number of items from your data.  Select2 should pass which items to skip and take to your controller.

**Edit:**

Try changing this:

```
$.post(urlContent + 'Cutomer/GetCustomerDDL', Json, function(data) {
}, 'json').done(function(data) {
    customers = data;
    $ddlCustomers.select2({
        placeholder: "Select Customer(s)",
        allowClear: true,
        multiple: true,
        data: customers
    });
});
```

to this:

```
$ddlCustomers.select2({
    ajax: {
      url: urlContent + 'Cutomer/GetCustomerDDL',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          q: term, // search term
          pageLimit: 10,
          page: page, // page number
          client: client
        };
      },
      results: function (data, page) {
        var more = (page * 10) < data.total; // whether or not there are more results available
        return { results: data.customers, more: more };
      }
    },
});
```

On your controller, you'll want to return your sub-list of customers in a "customers" property, and the total customers in a "total" property.

```
return Json(new { customers = customers.Skip(...).Take(...), 
  total = customers.Count() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Sample json result:

```
{ customers: [...], total: 2000 }
```

Comment: I know how to handle the server-side and I was looking at the homepage for Select2, but I am not how to modify the javascript.

Comment: The Select2 page has an example javascript for infinite loading.  The key will be setting the `ajax` properties correctly (`url`, `data`, `results`, etc.)

Comment: yes, I saw that, since I am not familiar with javascript, I am not sure where to set those in my example even with the Select2 help.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some sample code.  Hopefully it helps.

Comment: It now tells me data is null in the firebug console.  Before I was able to get the client value passed from the javascript to my controller method, but now that is not there.  What happened to my Json object?

Comment: See my update.  I added it to the json data sent to the controller.

Comment: client is part of an object I called Json, for example, `var Json{}; Json.client = client;`  I have more variables, but I tried settting Json : Json in the return part of the data function, but it tells me data is null.